# Why doesn't the gnuplot grid extend over this whole plot?

Tags: gnuplot

Using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1, with the following commands,

```
set grid linewidth 1 linecolor rgb"#888888"
set datafile separator ","
plot for [n=2:100] "data.csv" using 1:(column(n)) with lines linewidth 2
```

and the following example data in the file "data.csv",

```
time,S1,S2
0,0.00015,0
0.1,0.0001357256127053939,1.427438729460607e-005
0.2,0.0001228096129616973,2.719038703830272e-005
0.3,0.0001111227331022577,3.887726689774233e-005
0.4,0.0001005480069053459,4.945199309465411e-005
0.5,9.097959895689501e-005,5.902040104310499e-005
0.6,8.232174541410396e-005,6.767825458589604e-005
0.7,7.448779556871142e-005,7.551220443128858e-005
0.8,6.739934461758323e-005,8.260065538241677e-005
0.9,6.098544896108986e-005,8.901455103891014e-005
1,5.518191617571635e-005,9.481808382428365e-005
```

the resulting plot looks this:

[image]

Question: why does the grid only extend partway from the bottom, and not cover the whole plot?  I tried a considerable amount of experimentation with the set xtics and ytics commands, arguments to grid, and more, and have not been able to get the grid to cover the whole plot.  What am I missing?

Comment: Which OS/terminal and version of gnuplot are you using?  The grid looks fine for me (covering the whole plot) using the data and commands you provided.  I am running Arch Linux/gnuplot 4.6.1 and using the png and eps terminals.

Comment: I'm using the MacPorts version of gnuplot (the version identifier reads as "4.6.1_0+aquaterm+luaterm+pangocairo+x11") on Mac OS X 10.8.2 system. It happens to me whether I use the SVG terminal or the Aqua terminal.  I just tried the PNG terminal, but it happens with that too.  Hmmm.  But the fact it doesn't happen to you is very interesting.

Comment: @andyras -- Try it with the x11 terminal (I was able to reproduce it on OS-X 10.5.8)

Comment: I just gave it a try, and I also have the grid covering the complete plot. Using `gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 4` on a linux machine... and @mgilson: I cannot reproduce it with x11 terminal

Comment: @Woltan -- What terminal?  I can reproduce this using the x11 terminal using gnuplot 4.6.0 (OS-X 10.5.8) and gnuplot 4.6.1 (Ubuntu Linux)

Comment: I tried it using 4.6.1 built from sources, and I get the same behavior.  Relative to the answer by @mgilson below, could it be that those of you who don't experience the problem have commands in a .gnuplot file that unset the key or somehow configure it so that is not shown in the same way as in the default configuration?

Comment: @mhucka -- There definitely is a difference -- Although I'm not sure why andyras didn't see this.

Comment: Woops. I deleted my comment about the possibility of a difference in behavior between the versions because the first commenter said it happened on 4.6.1 for them, but I guess the comment was visible long enough for @mgilson to see it and respond :-). Thanks, and sorry about that; unfortunately the comment will be out of sequence now. My bad.

Comment: @mhucka -- See my revised post demonstrating at least some differences between gnuplot versions.

Comment: @mgilson: very helpful. Thanks for those examples.

Comment: @mhucka -- I've opened a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3595233&group_id=2055&atid=102055) on sourceforge.  We'll see what Ethan and the other gnuplot devs think of this one :-)

Comment: @mgilson and others: I should say that I used the command `plot for [n=2:3]...` instead of `[n=2:100]` to avoid all the warnings due to the missing data columns before even looking at the plot output!  When I use the same commands as you all, I also see the key obscuring the plot.

Comment: @andyras -- Ahh, very good.  I was beginning to be concerned :-).  It would be very surprising to me if gnuplot behaved that differently on different flavors of linux. -- And of course, that is the most sensible fix for this one if the number of columns is known ahead of time

Comment: @mgilson: yes, I was also a little worried.  Now I wonder if Woltan did the same thing I did, or if his system is actually different.

Comment: @andyras -- Well, there's definitely different behavior between 4.4.2 and 4.6.  It had to change sometime.  Perhaps there was a short amount of time (4.4.4) where it worked as intended. -- this is kind of fun.  We have the convergence of the 3 highest scoring gnuplot answerers on this question :)

Comment: @andryas -- Regarding your note about [n=2:3] versus what I used: oh! Now I understand how the key could have covered so much space. It's not the default behavior of gnuplot here, but the fact that it was generating warnings that made the key so large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!  In fact, the answer is that the grid *does cover the whole plot*.  The problem is that the key is taking over.  Try it again, but with an `unset key` in there before your plot command.

What's happening is that gnuplot is reserving space in the key for all of the columns which have no data.  Nothing gets put in the space that was reserved since no reasonable data was found.  Ultimately, this pushes the 2 lines that were visible out of the viewable canvas area as well.

I've reproduced this using the x11, png, postscript and pngcairo terminals.

Note that this behavior seems to be version dependent:

With gnuplot 4.4.2 (OS-X, png terminal)

[image]

With gnuplot 4.6.0 (OS-X, png terminal)

[image]

For those using gnuplot 4.4.4, perhaps there was a bug fix which made it work for gnuplot 4.4.4 and then a regression.  It seems to persist into gnuplot 4.7.0 as well.  I might file a bug report.

Comment: <slaps head>. Yup, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that 4.6.x didn't show anything at all made this problem difficult to understand.  Had it shown the legend some way as in 4.4, I would have known immediately to suspect the key. And in fact, I _did_ suspect it could have been due to the key, but my attempts at manipulating the key didn't seem to have much effect.  (That's probably due to my relative lack of skill with gnuplot.)